# cron tab (or celery, whichever is best) - best way to register for certain days

Tags: python, django, cron

I want to implement a reminder system, where a reminder email will be sent to the users based on some date field in their userprofile.How can I implement this ? Many suggested me not to use celery. Told me to use cron tab.

This is how I do, is this good way? If not, please suggest me a good way.

If cron:
     Planning to run a python management command daily, that will check if there is some reminder for that day, by checking dates of all the users.
I dont think this is good, I think, whenever the user select their reminder date, then that date will be registered some how and job will be run only on that date, but I am not getting how to implement this.
Way I know to implement this:
Create a database table named 'reminderdates', and whenever a reminder is registered, add that date and user_id to that table. So, run a cron job everyday that checks if that day is among the dates in the table. If yes job will be run. Also, I will run another cron job that will delete all the older reminderdates from the table so the table size wont get increased with time.

Comment: Is reminder date is the DateField or DateTimeField? if Time does not matter here then i'll suggest you to use django management command + crontab.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to setup a cron job to hit a URL on the site that performs the task. I would recommend Celery though. Here's why (from [Django/Celery Quickstart](http://chase-seibert.github.com/blog/2010/07/09/djangocelery-quickstart-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-using-cron-and-love-celery.html)):

> > > Cron has the advantage of simplicity, but it's not not ideal for the job. You have to take steps to ensure that regular users of the site cannot hit those URLs directly. It also forces you to manage an external configuration. What if you forget to perform the configuration on the qa or production servers? It would be safer and easier if the configuration was in the code for the site.

You will find a tutorial on how to implement tasks with celery on that previous link.

As for your `reminderdates` table idea, it should work. You can simplify it a little bit if you try this:

1. Adding a column with a sent status. Your task will check for date and sent status. If current day matches reminder date AND status is "unsent", then send the reminder.
2. You don't need a secondary cron job to delete older reminders. The same task that sends the reminders can send each one and delete it after (in which case the sent/unsent status would not be needed).